# How to select and display PDF and Image file in a same component Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to angular4, I am trying to display a pdf file and a image file in a component .

In this I have facing a problem as follows.

whenever I select a image it get display but when I select a pdf the selected image  is replaced and also the pdf file also not get displayed.

I have placed my code in stackblitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq5ro5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestions-stepper%2Fquestions-stepper.component.html

can anyone help me to fix this .

HTML

```
<!-- Image File -->

<button class="col-sm-12 stylings" 
mat-raised-button (click)="file.click()">{{caption}}</button>
<input hidden type="file" accept="image/*" #file onclick="this.value = null" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
<mat-card class="col-sm-12" style="padding:4px">
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
<img [src]="selectedImage" class="img-responsive img" /></div>
</mat-card>

  <!-- Pdf File -->

  <button class="col-sm-12 stylings" 
mat-raised-button (click)="file.click()">{{captionPdf}}</button>
<input hidden type='application/pdf' accept="application/pdf" #file1 onclick="this.value = null" (change)="onSelectPdfFile($event)">
<mat-card class="col-sm-12" style="padding:4px">
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
<img [src]="selectedPdf" class="img-responsive img" /></div>
</mat-card>
```

typescript

```
 onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToUpload);
      reader.onload = e => this.selectedImage = reader.result.toString();
      this.caption = event.target.files[0].name;
    }
  }

onSelectPdfFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.imageToUpload = event.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToUpload);
      reader.onload = e => this.selectedPdf = reader.result.toString();
      this.caption = event.target.files[0].name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: make sure that in your pdf section, you write file1.click not file.click

Answer (score 0):

Under PDF section, you need to use file1.click(). Also change input type='file.'

```
<button class="col-sm-12 stylings" 
mat-raised-button (click)="file1.click()">{{captionPdf}}</button>
<input hidden type='file' accept="application/pdf" #file1 onclick="this.value = null" (change)="onSelectPdfFile($event)">
```

You can use  to preview PDF document.

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(selectedPdf)" width="200px" height="200px"></iframe></div>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcirtt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestions-stepper%2Fquestions-stepper.component.html

Comment: bro,How to display the selected pdf file @Suresh Kumar Ariya

Comment: It will not working in mobile device, trust me. there is library can handle this. install this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer`